# Error in composer.json file after installing module

Tags: php, module, installation, phpmailer

I have run the command to run `composer require phpmailer/phpmailer` which created a file `composer.json` and `composer.lock`, however, the first one shows an error in the opening bracket { and says "Missing property name, missing property description". Why doesn't add those properties automatically or how to add them in a proper way so I don't cause any other issue?

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: If you run `composer init` in your project and answer the questions, it will populate those fields automatically.

Comment: Googling for the error messages leads to https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/473, which tells you that there are some fields missing.